# Changing javascript method to ajax .load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I was creating a website with a function that would allow me to load content dynamically. I was able to achieve it, but I wanted to use the Ajax `.load()` function.

http://jsfiddle.net/x9bvLwjL/17/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $modal = $("#myModal");
  var src = "";

  $('.image-wrap img').click(function() {
    $img = $(this);
    console.log($img.next('p').text());
    $modal.find('img').attr('src', $img.attr('src'));
    $modal.find('.modalheader').text($img.attr('alt'));
    $modal.find('.desc').text($img.next('p').text());
    $modal.show();
  });


  $('#myModal .close').click(function() {
    $modal.hide();
  });
});
```

As you seen when you click on the images, each image loads that image itself with a different text description. I want the webpage to do exactly the same thing just using `.load()` instead.

Comment: What's the question exactly?  Just use the function for the entire page...

Comment: im so sorry I was also supposed to add this http://jsfiddle.net/x9bvLwjL/17/

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Do you not know how time the `load` function or is it not working.

Comment: I am asking how to change the current function I have into using ajax .load

Comment: Please include the most relevant snippets of code within your post. The error you likely got by trying to include the JSFiddle link would've given you that instruction. Don't ignore it.

Comment: And there is no junction that does any sort of loading in your fiddle.

Comment: That what I am trying to do

Comment: Perhaps explaining where you plan to store your movies data and in which format... ?! JSON ? Plain text? HTML?

Comment: I plan on storing them in html file

Comment: @sai pelase click [edit] and improve your question.

Comment: @sai you can store everything inside a single HTML file or in different files... what's your plan?

Comment: I want to store everything in a single HTML file

Comment: Thats what I want to do I want to import content stored in a separate location

Comment: Would I only put my modal in the  html file or would i have to put in the paragraph text of the images as well